# Will android mobile OS support css file format?

Tags: android, mobile, operating-system, client-server

I am developing an android server-client application which will draw the user requested interfaces dynamically. The interfaces will transfered to the client from the server according to the requirement. To access the fields of the interface file, and manage it well, can I use css file format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you render the document in the WebView user interface control
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: if my answer is acceptable, remember to select it as the chosen answer (select the tick so it goes green). You get points on stackoverflow for doing that